# Python selenium wait until element has text (when it didn't before)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait, expected-condition

There is a div that is always present on the page but doesn't contain anything until a button is pressed.
Is there a way to wait until the div contains text, when it didn't before, and then get the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` provides `text_to_be_present_in_element` condition for that.
The syntax is as following:

```py
wait.until(EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.ID, "modalUserEmail"), "expected_text"))
```

Afte using the following imports and initializations:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
```

Used here locator `By.ID, "modalUserEmail"` is for example only. You will need to use proper locator matching relevant web element.
**UPD**
In case that element has no text content before the action and will have some text content you can wait for the following XPath condition:

```py
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='unique_class'][text()]")))
```

`//div[@class='unique_class']` here is unique locator for that element and `[text()]` means that element has some text content.
**UPD2**
If you want to get the text in that element you can apply `.text` on the returned web element. Also, in this case it is better to use `visibility_of_element_located`, not just `presence_of_element_located`, so your code can be as following:

```py
the_text_value = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='unique_class'][text()]"))).text
```

Comment: I don't have a text that I expect though, it it variable. I just want text to be present, but don't want to specify a specific text

Comment: So, you mean before clicking the button no text there (even not a space!) but after the action the text content is not empty?

Comment: exactly, the div is empty and then there is text after pressing a button

Comment: how would I grab the text from the wait.until

Comment: It returns the web element, so applying `.text` on it will give you that text. I'll update the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own custom expected condition that check for change in the text of the div

```
class DivTextToChange:
    current_text = ''
    def __call__(self, driver):
        elem = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "/html/xpath/to/div")
        if elem:
            text = elem.get_attribute('innerText')
            if text and text != DivTextToChange.current_text:
                DivTextToChange.current_text = text
                return text
        return False
```

to use:

```
text = WebDriverWait(driver, timeout=30).until(DivTextToChange())
```